# Tag synonym request [trophies] -> [achievements]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[It seems that we already have](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/achievements/synonyms) [steam-achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-achievements) and [live-achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-achievements) as synonyms for [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements), but there are 21 questions tagged [trophies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trophies). Since we have the Xbox's and PC's achievements merged, we should probably merge the PS3's as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good shootin', pardner.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be reconsidered.

They're not *called* achievements for PlayStation 3: they're called trophies. When someone is searching for info and they're a PS3 player, they search for trophies, which we will no longer rank on because of this change unless someone has the foresight to add the word trophy in the body (thus defeating the purpose of the tag synonym in the first place).

For example, the only reason we rank on certain Dungeon Siege III trophies in Google is because "trophies" is still indexed:

- [dungeon siege 3 trophies worthy of legend](http://www.google.com/search?q=dungeon+siege+3+trophies+worthy+of+legend&start=19)

  > The **trophy** for **Worthy of Legend** reads: You completed **Dungeon Siege** III at the ... Browse other questions tagged achievements **trophies dungeon-siege-3** or ask ...
- [dungeon siege royalist ally trophy](http://www.google.com/search?q=dungeon+siege+royalist+ally+trophy)

  > **Royalist Ally** - You have shown unwavering support to the Crown. It seems odd to have two **trophies** for the same thing. ... Browse other questions tagged ps3 spoiler achievements **dungeon-siege-3** or ask your own question. ...
- [I Could Do This Blindfolded trophy](http://www.google.com/search?q=I+Could+Do+This+Blindfolded+trophy)

  > In Dungeon Siege III, the **trophy**/achievement **I Could Do This Blindfolded** reads: You defeated a major opponent using only your default equipment. ...

Put another way, if we have to mention both achievements and trophies in order to rank for the two main audiences for a particular console game, they're not really synonyms in the classical sense. I don't know what we're serving by combining the two into one.

Yes, it kinda sucks for tagging that Sony decided to be a special little flower and call their system trophies, but we should only be using the tagging system for *descriptive* organization, not normative.

Comment: The trophies are achievements though. Splitting them up to improve our SEO would be like breaking a [gil] tag off of [money] for Final Fantasy, a [credits] tag for Gran Turismo, a [gold] tag for WoW, or a [meat] tag for KoL.

Comment: @Ullalulloo None of those tags are useful, though. If there is actually a money tag being used, it should be purged with fire: it's unreasonable to presume gamers would want to answer or follow questions about money in all its forms in completely unrelated games, but it's not unreasonable to presume they'd want to follow achievement/trophy questions. Calling trophies achievements & expecting PS3 users search for achievements instead of trophies because everyone else uses them that is something akin to saying iPhones should be tagged Android because all the other phone vendors use that.

Comment: @Ullalullo Tagging should always be first and foremost what people use, not what we want them to use because it makes organization easier on us.

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Personally, I don't really see much benefit in most of the tags other than the games, but I don't want to get into that, and we already have it. iPhones aren't Androids though, they're competitors; achievements is the most general word for trophies, badges, medals, etc. If tagging should be what people use, not for organization, then why have any tag synonyms? btw, my name has six 'l's in it.

Comment: I have been waffling over this and I think I have to agree with this on the grounds of google indexability and the oft-promoted use of tags on the site for sorting/ignoring purposes. For example, for Prototype, a game that was released for both 360 and PS3, the google results for one of the achievements, "Endless Hunger," are drastically different. [4.7 mil](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=endless+hunger+achievement) vs. [1.7 mil](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=Endless+Hunger+trophy).

Comment: The top sites in this case that are indexed for "achievements" are usually 360/PC-sites whereas those indexed for "trophies" are usually PS3-based sites. Considering that we are platform-neutral, I think that it would be prudent to keep the "trophies" tag separate for index ranking purposes.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes And what about platform-independent questions? If the achievementrophy is the same on both platforms, it should be tagged with both.

Comment: @Arda Personally, if the method is the same between both platforms, I don't see a huge problem with that if it'll increase SOE for us and help more people find us to use as a resource.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes That means every question about a game that's also on the PS3 tagged with achievement should also be tagged as trophy and vice versa. That's exactly what synonyms are for.

Comment: @Arda But that still won't put us in the search index for trophies, unless I'm misunderstanding how synonyms work. From doing more googling, it seems on average that searches for multiplatform game achievementrophies (I like that word), searches with "trophies" only return 1/3 or so the number of results. IMO, we want to *be* in that 1/3.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Okay, so we should just make both a synonym of achievementrophy. I do get what you mean, I just think that there's a conflict of interest between tagging for sorting and tagging for SEO purposes.